# How to set "Alarms & Clocks" category for an extension in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I have a question about Google Chrome extension development if there are people with relevant experience out there.

I have created a timer extension for Google Chrome but when I want to publish it, there is no "Alarms & Clocks" category in the dashboard. The closest I could find is "Productivity". But I want my extension to be listed under [alarms and clocks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/app/90-alarms-and-clocks).

This is what I see in the **Developer Dashboard > Edit Item**:

[image]

I literally typed "Alarms & Clocks" in "Additional Categories" but it didn't help either. How do people set those categories like "Utilities", "Education", etc. that you can see in [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/home)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that promotional images for extensions are reviewed by Google employees. This quality control may also include setting detailed categories. To help them choose use `Additional categories (comma-separated):` option. Description for it states:

> Enter additional categories that describe your item. We will use them
>   to improve our selection of categories.